# Error preloading model resource in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ocr, google-mlkit, text-recognition

I am trying to use Google's MLKit in Android Studio, but no matter which MLKit Vision app I'm trying to start, I keep getting the following error in my Logcat:

> Error preloading model resource
> com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Waiting for the text optional
> module to be downloaded. Please wait.

And further:

> at
> com.google.mlkit.vision.text.internal.zzb.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common@@18.0.0:22)
> at
> com.google.mlkit.vision.text.internal.TextRecognizerTaskWithResource.load(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition-common@@18.0.0:1)
> at
> com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.ModelResource.zza(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.5.0:4)
> at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzn.run(Unknown Source:10)
> at
> com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzt.run(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.5.0:2)
> at
> com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zze(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.5.0:4)
> at
> com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzc(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.5.0:1)
> at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzk.run(Unknown Source:2)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
> at
> com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzd(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.5.0:2)
> at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzi.run(Unknown Source:2)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

Depending on the app, the app itself still loads, but the OCR module (or TextRecognizer) wouldn't work.

System specs:

- Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon
- Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2

So, my system is up to date. So are the plugins I'm using in Android Studio.

I was very surprised to see that apparently nobody ever had this or similar issues in Android Studio. Still, help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a simulator to run? By default simulator wont have a gmscore so it cannot download optional module for you. You can either:

1. test on a real device or a simulator with gmscore
2. use bundled SDK instead.

Comment: Thank you!!! I've had this issue for ages, can't believe nobody ever mentions that there are emulators with and without Google Play Store installed. I always figured they should be the same in terms of software specs...